# Unable to load texture on md2 model

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, rajawali

I'm trying to use Rajawali framework to load a texture on md2 model. But I just can't get it done. It doesn't show any error but only some warnings. I'm not really sure whether it's my code issue or the texture issue. I managed to load the model though.

```
    MD2Parser parser = new MD2Parser(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager, R.raw.fighter);
    parser.parse();

    mOgre = (VertexAnimationObject3D) parser.getParsedAnimationObject();
    mOgre.addLight(mLight);
    DiffuseMaterial material = new DiffuseMaterial(true);
    Bitmap texture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.fighter);
    TextureManager tTextureManager = new TextureManager();
    TextureInfo tInfo = tTextureManager.addTexture(texture);
    mOgre.setMaterial(material);
    mOgre.setPosition(0, 0, 20);
    mOgre.setY(-1);

    addChild(mOgre);

    mOgre.addTexture(tInfo);
    mOgre.play();
```

Any comment and answer will be appreciated!